# Assign User to a field on another object

Tags: administration, fields

Hi I am a beginner in SF.

I am trying to create a process or a field update where I need ac account field to show information from another field on another object:

Account Object field "vCISO Assigned" should show the same value (user) that is on the "Primary Security Analyst" field on the Project object.

What ways can I accomplish this with? Thanks in advance for your help.

PROJECT:
[image]

ACCOUNT:
[image]

Comment: Can you logically describe the relationship of the data? It seems to me that there is no direct connection between the account object and the project object.

Comment: @J.Schreiber The project record is related to the account record because it is the project we are working on for that client. I updated the question with screenshots.

Comment: Having 1 question, What is the case, when same `account` available more then 1 `Project` records, which Primary Security Analyst` field value need to be shown in `account` field `vCISO Assigned`?

Comment: @MohanRaj The Project Type field on the Project should be "vCISO" for it to map.